# How to validate Uppercase in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a  **MVC** project, I want to validate it for some **text filed** are **uppercase**. How can I do it? 
I'm using this `**text-transform:uppercase**` but I want to validate in **model**

```
[DisplayName("Last Name :")]
            [Required]
            [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Last Name must be between 3 and 50 characters!")]
            public string LastName { get; set; }
```

Comment: Use a `RegularExpressionAttribute` which allows only uppercase characters, but why not just covert the value to uppercase before saving to the database if that'w what you want?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, note that case conversion is a task fraught with peril. See [the Turkish "i" problem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973919.aspx#stringsinnet20_topic5) for example. Granted, not everybody cares...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[RegularExpression(@"[A-Z]{3,50}$", 
         ErrorMessage = "Only uppercase Characters are allowed.")]
```

use regular expression attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Welcome. Happy to help.

Comment: What about hyphenated last names.